# Weird Line When Wrapping Image in Fragment Shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have made a simple fragment shader using THREE.js. It reads each pixel's coordinate, adds a value to the x component (wrapping to 0 if it goes above 1), and returns the color of a background image at this new location. This has the effect of shifting the background image over and wrapping the part that goes off-screen. The problem is that a dark line sometimes appears where the edge of the image is shifted over:

[image: here is a picture]

Here is my code:

```js
var vertexShader = `
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
`;

var fragmentShader = `
varying vec2 vUv;

uniform sampler2D background;

void main() {
  float x = mod(vUv.x + 0.47, 1.0);
  float y = vUv.y;

  gl_FragColor = texture(background, vec2(x, y));
}
`;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var plotElement = $("#plot");

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0, 1000);

  renderer.setSize(500, 500);
  plotElement.append(renderer.domElement);

  var background = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://wearablewearyphase.davidbrock1.repl.co/background.png');

  var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
    uniforms: {
      background: {
        value: background
      },
    },
  });

  geom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1);
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
  camera.z = 1;

  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  render();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r118/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="plot"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am quite sure that the line is not in the original image:

[image: original image]

The boundary should not be visible at all because the left and right sides are the same color. Furthermore, the line only appears for some shift distances (49% and 47%, but not 50% or 48%, for example). I have found that if I make the output bigger than the background image than the line disappears, but I would prefer not to do this.

What is causing this line and how can I prevent it?

Note:
I just used the "mod" function as an example. Originally, I had another program (another shader) calculate x and y coordinates for every pixel and save them in another texture as the red and green components. The fragment shader then looked these coordinates up in the image.

I ran into this problem while trying to create an animation like [this](https://observablehq.com/@rreusser/the-double-pendulum-fractal). The lines started appearing all over the screen and did not look good.

Comment: I am really not into webGL nor Three so excuse me if my comment is completely off, but fast looking at the docs, why not make your texture repeat and remove that `mod()`? I'd imagine the flooring there is the cause of this line. https://jsfiddle.net/qsp5vz3j/

Comment: Thanks. The "mod" function was really just an example, and I edited my question to say this.  If it would be helpful, I can post a link to my original (more complicated) code.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the fragment shader interpolates values across pixels. So one pixel column approaches `1.0`, the next one is a very squished version of your entire texture between `1.0 - 0.0`, and the next one starts over at `0.0`.

The easiest way to circumvent this behavior is to set [your texture's wrapping mode to `THREE.RepeatWrapping`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture.wrapS) and get rid of the `mod()` so as your texture goes above 1.0, it'll automatically start over from the left again.

Comment: Thanks! Does the interpolation happen before or after the fragment shader runs? I thought the fragment shader ran once for every pixel on the screen, so would not need to do any interpolation. Also, if the fragment shader just returns a color,  how would the computer have any knowledge of the texture it came from (and use it instead of the color returned for interpolating)?